# In Android Navigation drawer app:showAsAction="collapseActionView" Not working

Tags: android

i am using following code

```
 <item
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/sub_menu"
    android:title="Other">

    </item>
```

I also uses app:showAsAction="never" it also not working.

Comment: replace app with android .http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html

Answer (score 0):

Use  `android:showAsAction="collapseActionView"` instead of `app:showAsAction="collapseActionView"`

This will work

Comment: android:showAsAction="collapseActionView" also not working although in actionbar option menu both are working but in Navigation drawer none of them working.